# Some cookie makes Play! answer with an err_empty_response

Tags: cookies, playframework-2.0

I have a JS plugin (getvero.com) that creates a cookie like that

> [{"command":["events_track","Visited site",{},{"time":1377020238096}],"job_id":"1377020238097_9041"},{"command":["events_track","Visited Site",{"URL":"http://mywebsite.com/discoveries/","Referrer":"Direct","_n":"Visited Site","_k":"cd4dde369919a1626d13a28d1d54bc11bdc7f48d","_p":"qLipS0SbtoTOfJCUyiyRjoCQFFo=","_t":1377020242},{"time":1377020241741}],"job_id":"1377020241741_235"},{"command":["events_track","Visit all discoveries",{"_n":"Visit all discoveries","_k":"cd4dde369919a1626d13a28d1d54bc11bdc7f48d","_p":"qLipS0SbtoTOfJCUyiyRjoCQFFo=","_t":1377020242},{"time":1377020241752}],"job_id":"1377020241752_8389"}]

which makes play answer an err_empty_response when I ask for a page without removing the cookie.

I was with play 2.0.4, I upgraded to 2.0.6 but didn't make it work.

Seems close to this issue : http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1618-long-cookies-with-double-quote-values-make-play-fail-before-the-request-is-handled

I'll try 2.1 later.
Otherwise, any idea ?

Comment: An additional question : any way to delete this creepy cookie? Otherwise, I'm gonna remove this plugin but the cookie will remain and the issue wont disappear ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Play 2.1 made it work.